# Patch unable to find file

Tags: diff, patch

I am currently in directory - `/usr/lib/llvm-9/build`

The `include/` directory is a symlink -

```
reikdas@reikdas-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/llvm-9/build$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 31 2020 include -> ../include
```

But since I will be patching this via a script, I cannot manually put in the actual path of the symlink.

I have a `.diff` file that looks like this -

```
diff --git a/include/llvm/Demangle/MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h b/include/llvm/Demangle/MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h
index da9d9d5bfdc..3d47471f0ef 100644
--- a/include/llvm/Demangle/MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h
+++ b/include/llvm/Demangle/MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h
@@ -16,6 +16,8 @@
 #include "llvm/Demangle/DemangleConfig.h"
 #include "llvm/Demangle/StringView.h"
 #include <array>
+#include <cstdint>
+#include <string>
 
 namespace llvm {
 namespace itanium_demangle {
```

I do - `patch -p1 < nameofthepatch.diff`

but, I get an error -

```
Can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading upto this was:
....
File to patch:
```

But the file does exist -

```
reikdas@reikdas-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/llvm-9/build$ ls include/llvm/Demangle/ | grep MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h
MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h
```

I get the same error with - `patch -p1 --follow-symlinks < nameofthepatch.diff`

(please note that I specified which directory I executed these commands from)

The diff was generated on a Linux machine, so there are no hidden carriage returns.

Also, this works -

```
patch -p1 include/llvm/Demangle/MicrosoftDemangleNodes.h nameofthepatch.diff
```

which is not tenable, since a single `.diff` file might contain the diff for multiple files.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux, did you try with the `--follow-symlinks` option to `patch`?

Comment: I get the same error with `--follow-symlinks` (I had forgotten to add that to the post - should be there now).